# Выборка при условии что строчка начинается с цифр

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Содержимое поля может содержать любые символы. Задача в том, чтобы выбрать все записи содержимое поля которых начинается с числа. Ни с символа, ни с букву, ни с пробела. Именно с числа, то есть первый символ в поле является числом.

Как правильно сделать выборку под такое условие?

Comment: ```WHERE column REGEXP '^\\d'```

Comment: Не работает, не выхватывает ни одной записи, после цифры могут быть еще цифры или букву и символы и тд. Быть может тут дело в чем?

Comment: Или криво применил, или данные отличаются от описания. Выложи CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO со значениями, на которых у тебя "не работает". https://dbfiddle.uk/sNZBODJD